# Add a timestamp and info to a saved CSS/HTML file

Tags: css, sublimetext2, dreamweaver, adobe-brackets

Looking for a way to add a custom timestamp(and maybe some extra info) inside a CSS/HTML file everytime you save the file. Is there an extention for brackets, sublime or dreamweaver that does this, Or perhaps some other way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17727020/630092) will give you a Sublime Text plugin that should do what you ask.

Comment: Great, please accept my answer so others reading your question will know what the accepted resolution was that worked for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In [Brackets](http://www.brackets.io/), you can configure the [snippets extension](https://github.com/jrowny/brackets-snippets) to insert a timestamp manually, like the answer above for Sublime. Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18844762/1172352.

Similar to the Sublime answer, it would be a bit trickier to do it *automatically* every time you save. There's not yet a clean hook in Brackets for pre-save processing. [Several](https://github.com/pockata/brackets-StripTrailingSpaces/blob/master/main.js#L82) [extensions](https://github.com/dsbonev/whitespace-normalizer/blob/master/main.js#L73) get around this by listening for a post-save event and saving quickly a second time. You could probably write a timestamp-auto-inserter extension by borrowing their code for that pattern.

Anything that runs automatically would also need a little extra code to find the old timestamp and replace it -- both the snippets solution here and the Sublime solution above just insert the timestamp wherever the cursor/selection is. A regular expression should do the trick for detection.

You'd also want to screen out other file types. Bringing it all together, it would look something like this for Brackets:

```
function documentSavedHandler(event, doc) {
    // TODO: need a little extra code here to ignore save events triggered
    // by ourself, to avoid infinite loop

    var langId = doc.getLanguage().getId();
    if (langId === "html" || langId === "css") {
        var pos = /* use regexp to find old timestamp */;
        doc.replaceRange(timestampStr, posStart, posEnd);
        CommandManager.execute(Commands.FILE_SAVE);
    }
}
```